# API Call(s) To get Number Of Commits by Author GitHub API

Tags: php, wordpress, github-api

I am trying to create a WordPress widget that displays a user's repository information and number of commits (limited to the last 30 days). I got the repository info very easily, but am struggling with the second part. I'm using PHP in this case, and displaying the info in a WordPress widget.

Basically I need the API to return the number of commits that a user made in a given month across all (public) repositories. Is there any easy endpoint to access this, or will I have to loop through each of the user's repositories active in the last month and pull the number of commits from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to [list events for a given user](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-events-performed-by-a-user)

```
GET /users/:username/events
```

Example: https://api.github.com/users/VonC/events

```
{
    "id": "3406063602",
    "type": "PushEvent",
    "actor": {
      "id": 79478,
      "login": "VonC",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/VonC",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/79478?"
    },
    "repo": {
      "id": 47265668,
      "name": "VonC/hello-world-go",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/VonC/hello-world-go"
    },
    "payload": {
      "push_id": 889397803,
      "size": 2,
      "distinct_size": 2,
      "ref": "refs/heads/master",
      "head": "54dd9bd15fea2476bd76c7bf88bcec370d9dfc61",
      "before": "64d3b59911fef0b0c2423c105c38aabf99332e28",
      "commits": [
        {
          "sha": "ee856fa87073cf92e11baa4d36f61394de937085",
          ...
```

You will have to filter for `PushEvent`, and [iterate over the pages of events](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination) until getting an event older than a month ago.

Comment: I like your thinking @vonC! This would likely require a lesser amount of API requests than doing it my way. Would I have to worry about pagination in this case?

Comment: @ZachRussell The events are limited at 30 per pages... which might not be enough to get all events on the past months. In that case, you will have to iterate for getting more pages.